# How to match function parameters to index signature interface definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and TypeScript and I'm trying to use the ['rpc-websockets'](https://github.com/elpheria/rpc-websockets) library.

An rpc call is registered on the server with this 'register()' method:

```
 /**
 * Registers an RPC method.
 * @method
 * @param {String} name - method name
 * @param {Function} fn - a callee function
 * @param {String} ns - namespace identifier
 * @throws {TypeError}
 * @return {Object} - returns an IMethod object
 */
register(name: string, fn: (params: IRPCMethodParams, socket_id: string) => void, ns?: string): IMethod;
```

Where `IRPCMethodParams` is defined as:

```
interface IRPCMethodParams {
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

I'm trying to use strict typing out of principle and I can't work out how to type the arguments of the function I pass as the 'fn' parameter.

Here's what I've tried and the compiler errors:

1.

```
import { Server } from 'rpc-websockets'

let rpc_server = new Server({ host: 'localhost', port: 9999 });

rpc_server.register('add',
    (params : {num1: number, num2: number}, socket_id: string): number => {
        return params.num1 + params.num2;
    }
)
```

Error:

```
src/minimal.ts:18:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(params: {    num1: number;    num2: number;}, socket_id: string) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: IRPCMethodParams, socket_id: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
    Type 'IRPCMethodParams' is missing the following properties from type '{ num1: number; num2: number; }': num1, num2

18     (params : {num1: number, num2: number}, socket_id: string): number => {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

2. 

```
rpc_server.register('add',
    ([num1, num2] : [number, number], socket_id: string): number => {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
)
```

Error:

```
src/minimal.ts:12:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '([num1, num2]: [number, number], socket_id: string) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: IRPCMethodParams, socket_id: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'params' are incompatible.
    Type 'IRPCMethodParams' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.

12     ([num1, num2] : [number, number], socket_id: string): number => {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This compiles but obviously I'm not really getting the benefit of the type system:

```
rpc_server.register('add',
    (params: {[x: string]: any}, _: string): number => {
        return params["num1"] + params["num2"];
    }
)
```

`IRPCMethodParams` is not exported by the library so I can't try to extend it.

Is it possible with how this 'register()' method is defined to type my 'fn' argument how I want (2 'number' arguments)? It seems as though `IRPCMethodParams` is specified so that 'fn' could accept any arbitrary arguments but I'm not understanding how to use it.

Comment: Specifying that callback accepts `IRPCMethodParams` doesn't mean "this callback may choose what subtype of `IRPCMethodParams` it wants to accept", it means "this callback will accept any value that is assignable to `IRPCMethodParams`". Therefore you cannot pass a callback that only accepts `{num1: number, num2: number}`. One option is to make `register` generic, so that you can choose at call time which `params` your callback wants to accept: `register<T>(..., fm: (params: T, ...) => ...)`

Comment: But keep in mind, that in that case it will be the responsibility of `register` to ensure, that `params` that it passes to `fn` are really of type `T`. For example if the caller of your RPC violates the types and calls `add` procedure with something other than `{num1: number, num2: number}`, typescript won't be able to detect this. For this you will need some runtime checks, either manual or using some kind of parser library (like superstruct/yup/zod/whatever)